# Can filemtime be compared with strtotime at the daylight savings change?

Tags: php, dst

I have some PHP code to send warnings and automatically shut down a service if the source data files are out of date. This is done using the following comparisons:

Warning:
`filemtime($file_location) < strtotime('-15 minute')`

Consider service down:
`filemtime($file_location) < strtotime('-1 hour')`

For 1 hour beginning at 3:00 AM CDT when daylight savings time begins, this incorrectly reports the file as being over 15 minutes old. Toward the end of the hour, it also incorrectly reports the file as being more than 1 hour old. At 4:00 AM CDT things return to normal.

Is there something I don't know about either the filemtime() or strtotime() functions that would explain this behaviour? It's my understanding that both return UNIX timestamps, and that timestamps are by definition in UTC, so I'm not sure what could cause this problem.

Based on the answers so far, I ran this test on our server:

`

```
for($i = 1; $i <=4; $i++){
    // let's say current time is this:
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Winnipeg');
    $current_timestamp = strtotime('2016-03-13 0'.$i.':00:00'); // 1457856060

    // DST start at 03:00 that day, so 60 minutes before the time should be 01:01
    $ts = $current_timestamp - 1*60*60;
    echo '-3600s:   ', $ts, ", ", date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts), "\n";
    // 1457852460, 2016-10-30 02:59:00, correct

    // now let's test strtotime with -1 hour
    $ts = strtotime('-1 hour', $current_timestamp);
    echo '-1 hour:  ', $ts, ", ", date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts), "\n";
    // 1457856060, 2016-10-30 03:01:00, completely wrong

    // DateTime implementation seems smarter:
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->setTimestamp($current_timestamp);
    $dt->sub(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
    echo 'sub PT1H: ', $dt->getTimestamp(), ", ", $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n";
    // 1457856060, 2016-10-30 03:01:00, correct

    echo "\n\n";
    echo 'TS        ', $current_timestamp, ", ", date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_timestamp), "\n";
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

`

-3600s:   1457848800, 2016-03-13 00:00:00

-1 hour:  1457848800, 2016-03-13 00:00:00

sub PT1H: 1457848800, 2016-03-13 00:00:00

TS        1457852400, 2016-03-13 01:00:00

-3600s:   1457852400, 2016-03-13 01:00:00

-1 hour:  1457856000, 2016-03-13 03:00:00

sub PT1H: 1457856000, 2016-03-13 03:00:00

TS        1457856000, 2016-03-13 03:00:00

-3600s:   1457852400, 2016-03-13 01:00:00

-1 hour:  1457856000, 2016-03-13 03:00:00

sub PT1H: 1457856000, 2016-03-13 03:00:00

TS        1457856000, 2016-03-13 03:00:00

-3600s:   1457856000, 2016-03-13 03:00:00

-1 hour:  1457856000, 2016-03-13 03:00:00

sub PT1H: 1457856000, 2016-03-13 03:00:00

TS        1457859600, 2016-03-13 04:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's deeply confusing. In my timezone, where daylight savings begins on 27 March, all of the following expressions return the same UNIX timestamp:

```
var_dump(strtotime("27 March 2016 02:00"));
var_dump(strtotime("- 60 minute", strtotime("27 March 2016 02:00")));
var_dump(strtotime("- 1 hour", strtotime("27 March 2016 02:00")));
var_dump(strtotime("27 March 2016 02:00 - 1 hour"));
var_dump((new DateTime("27 March 2016 02:00"))->format("U"));
var_dump((new DateTime("27 March 2016 02:00"))->sub(new DateInterval("PT1H"))->format("U"));
```

If I think hard enough about this, I could perhaps believe it's the intended behaviour. 01:00 on 27 March **does not exist here**. But it's certainly not intuitive.

Even more confusingly, subtracting 15 minutes from 02:00 gives an answer **in the future**, namely 02:45. Even if the first result makes a little sense if you squint enough, this result has got to be a bug.

There is [an open bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62185) about this which has been untouched for nearly 4 years.

This leaves you with two choices. You could add an `if` clause to your code, subtracting 2 hours or 75 minutes if the initial subtraction doesn't decrease the timestamp. Or you could simply subtract 3600 or 900 seconds from the current timestamp instead of using `strtotime`. Neither is particularly elegant, but there we are.

Comment: The open PHP bug is likely the source of the problem, although I still don't understand what's going on.

Comment: In your further test above, the answers obtained by subtracting 3600 from the timestamp are correct, whereas the other answers are wrong when they subtract enough time from a time in DT to take it back to ST. Hence 1am -1h is always midnight and 4am -1h is always 3am. 2am and 3am are **the same time**. Timestamp -3600 correctly returns 1am whereas using strtotime or DateInterval incorrectly returns 3am in both cases (ie no time is subtracted).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `strtotime` is not smart enough to take DST changes into consideration when operating on relative values:

```
// let's say current time is this:
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$current_timestamp = strtotime('2016-10-30 01:59:00'); // 1477785540

// DST ends at 03:00 that day, so 120 minutes later the time should be 02:59
$ts = $current_timestamp + 2*60*60;
echo $ts, ", ", date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts), "\n";
// 1477792740, 2016-10-30 02:59:00, correct

// now let's test strtotime with +2 hours
$ts = strtotime('+2 hours', $current_timestamp);
echo $ts, ", ", date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts), "\n";
// 1477796340, 2016-10-30 03:59:00, completely wrong

// DateTime implementation seems smarter:
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($current_timestamp);
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));
echo $dt->getTimestamp(), ", ", $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// 1477792740, 2016-10-30 02:59:00, correct
```

In your particular case I'd simply compare the timestamps directly (the difference would be in seconds, obviously), but using `DateTime` with `TimeInterval` is an option, too.

Comment: In my tests (added to the question, since there's too much code for a comment), using "-1 hour" with `strtotime` and "PT1H" with `DateTime` give the same timestamp. Not just the same as each other, the same as the base timestamp I'm adjusting from. At least during the problem hour.  Subtracting the total seconds, however, gives a different time stamp.